# Jitterbit run operation condition

Tags: jitterbit

I'm new to Jitterbit and I'm working in Jitterbit Studio 5.6.0.1. In our deployed project we have 4 consequential operations and the first one is scheduled. What I want to do is to put a condition on the first scheduled operation that it should not run until all operations from the previous run are finished. I want to avoid running the operation twice. Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I would suggest upgrading your studio to 8.12 (current version).  Aside from that, if you add a script before the operation that you want to check, you can use something along these lines:

```
isInQueue=GetOperationQueue("<TAG>Operations/Your_Operation</TAG>");
isRunning=isInQueue[0][1];
if(isRunning==1 && isRunning!=Null(),
  "Do Something";
);
```

That's just a very basic idea of how you can handle this.  In my situation, I have an operation that has just a script like this in it, that either direct to a script to run if not already running, or direct to a dead-end, if it needs to skip this scheduled instance.